# Go loop pointer changes

Tags: pointers, go, reference, slice

I am using a `for range` loop in Go to iterate through a slice of structs.

In each loop, I a pointer to the current item to a variable.

I am confused why the pointer changes value in the next loop.

For example [this code](http://play.golang.org/p/7Ruqt0pRB9):

```
package main

import "fmt"

type t struct {
    val int
}

func main() {
    l := []t{{1}, {2}}
    var p *t
    for _, i := range l {
        fmt.Println("begin", p)
        p = &i
        fmt.Println("end", p)
    }
}
```

I would expect to produce:

```
begin <nil>
end &{1}
begin &{1}
end &{2}
```

But actually does:

```
begin <nil>
end &{1}
begin &{2}
end &{2}
```

For reference, in my actual code, I am checking for a condition during the loop, and returning the current item and previous one. So I am trying to save a pointer to it, so that in the next iteration it will have access to the previous as well.

Comment: At the start of each loop iteration, `for`  is **copying** the current element of `l` into `i`.

Comment: So it reuses one `i` basically for the all the iterations?

I think that makes sense. How would I save a pointer to the actual object then, if I am in my loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're taking the address of the loop/range variable and not the address of the item in slice. However, you're just making a lot of unnecessary work for yourself. For one, why don't you use the `i, v := range` or better yet `i, _ :=` and then you can do `i-1` to get the previous item? Secondly, even if you want it saved in a pointer, still use this syntax and then assign `p = &l[i]` so you have the address of the item in the slice rather than the address of the loop/range variable.

People are way too eager to use for/each style constructs when it's obviously better to work with the index... If you want index-1 on every iteration, using the index should be your go to way of doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Building off [Tim's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32401933/go-loop-pointer-changes#comment52672262_32401933), it seems like you can copy the value on each loop, instead of the pointer, and dereference it after.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type t struct {
    val int
}

func main() {
    l := []t{{1}, {2}}
    var p t
    var i t
    for _, i = range l {
        fmt.Println("begin", &p)
        p = i
        fmt.Println("end", &p)
    }
}
```

Comment: see here for the FAQ entry: http://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines. The `i := i` idiom is probably the most common solution when you're not using a closure.

Comment: @JimB Thanks, that is very relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to get the pointer to the current item by using the index:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type t struct {
    val int
}

func main() {
    l := []t{{1}, {2}}
    var p *t

    for index, _ := range l {
        fmt.Println("begin", p)
        p = &l[index]
        fmt.Println("end", p)
    }
}
```